# Code::Blocks gives me some kind of permission error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, codeblocks

This code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello world!";
   return 0;
}
```

Gives me this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKgDM.png

And I have no idea why. 
Another user here had a solution. The solution was to open run and search for services.msc Find Application Experience and open it In General tab change Startup type to Automatic Hit Ok. but that did not work for me.

The code is example code from several c++ websites, and I presume that it should work.

Comment: Is this a fresh new project? (Or did your rename, modify, ... some build settings?)

Comment: First of all, do not post a picture of the error, but quote the error as text in the question itself. Then, as the problem at hand is obviously your environment setup and not your code, please give us detailed information about the former, i.e. OS, how you installed Code::Blocks, what settings you changed...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by build settings, but it was a "Hello World" program from the start.

Comment: As I said, the code itself is obviously fine, it is just a *"Hello world"* program. The problem lies in the your compiler/IDE setup, and so far, we know nothing about that. Thus, it is impossible to help you.

Comment: @Baum mit Augen 
First of all, I couldn't copy the error code, and I didn't feel like typing it all out. I'm a newbie and I don't really know what is important to show. 
Second, nothing is obvious if you're a noob like me. I installed Code::Blocks with it's default settings, and I don't know anything about this program or what the settings do.

Comment: So how do I find out what setup I have?

Comment: You probably ran C::B as administrator previously, but are not running it as administrator now. To fix this, either run as administrator, or go and delete the `.exe` file mentioned in the screenshot.

Comment: Another possibility is that access is denied because this `.exe` file is currently running. If that is the case, you'll get the same error when you try to delete the file. Look in Task Manager for the file and kill it.

Comment: @M.M
you were right, it was because C::B ran in administrator mode before. 
I deleted my whole workspace and started over, now it works! 
Thank you!

Comment: So you know going forward: anytime you have an error it is important to include it. It's highly preferred that you include it here and not require to see it in an image *unless* you have the rep to add an image directly in the post. As a side note, saying " I couldn't copy the error code, and I didn't feel like typing it all out. " does not encourage anyone to put a lot of effort in helping you. Especially when were' talking about a couple lines. You can shorten them by only giving the red portion and replacing the file with `file` for example.

Answer (score 0):

In your task manager, kill cb_console_runner.exe and Helloworld.exe and rebuild.